# Call near in amd64

Tags: linux, x86-64, elf, disassembly

I am reading the amd64 manual and in the CALL near section it says:

> For near calls in 64-bit mode, the operand size defaults to 64 bits. The E8 opcode
>   results in RIP = RIP + 32-bit signed displacement and the FF /2 opcode results in
>   RIP = 64-bit offset from register or memory. No prefix is available to encode a 32-bit
>   operand size in 64-bit mode.

It looks like that everytime the opcode is E8 the next 32 bits are used as offset, right? I disassembled a program and I tried:

```
  4003f0:       e8 3b 00 00 00          callq  400430 <__gmon_start__@plt>
```

According the manual the target address should be 0x4003f0 + 0x3b. If you try the result is 0x40042b, but according objdump it should be 0x400430. I tried with other call instructions and the same 4 bytes are missing, doesn anyone know the reason?

Also: it says the operand size is by default 64 bits and then says that only 32 bits are considered when the opcode is e8, is this an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just answering why it is `0x400430` and not `0x40042b`. While the instruction starts at `0x4003f0`, the EIP calculation is based on its next instruction, so you have to add 5 (the length of the current instruction) to EIP.

> The target operand specifies either an absolute offset in the code segment (an offset from the base of the code segment) or a relative offset (a signed displacement relative to the current value of the instruction pointer in the EIP register; this value points to the instruction following the CALL instruction).

(Quoted from the Intel manual.)